# Python is not freeing memory

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I've been working with XML resources, and it seems that Python is issuing a weird behavior. I've tested both `lxml` library and `xml.etree.ElementTree`, both holding memory after it should be collected by `gc`. I typed `gc.collect()` as a test, but nothing else happen: memory still being held by process.

Imports:

```
import time
from lxml import etree
import gc
```

This is the code:

```
def process_alternative():
    """
    This alternative process will use lxml
    """
    filename = u"/tmp/randomness.xml"
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    tree = etree.parse(fd)
    root = tree.getroot()

    accum = {}

    for _item in root.iter("*"):
        for _field in _item.iter("*"):
            if _field.tag in accum.keys():
                accum[_field.tag] += 1
            else:
                accum[_field.tag] = 1

    for key in accum.keys():
        print "%s -> %i" % (key, accum[key])

    fd.close()
    gc.collect()
```

And this is my main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        print "Wake up!"
        process_alternative()
        print "Sleeping..."
        time.sleep(30)
```

As you see, this main calls "process_alternative", and then sleep. XML file provided loads memory with nearly 800MB; so, before `time.sleep`, memory should be freed by process, returning to basic VM memory needed (around 32MB?). Instead, process continue holding around 800MB.

Any tip about why memory has not been freed after every iteration?

Using ubuntu 13.04, Python 2.7.4

This function deallocates memory in every iteration

```
def check_memory():
    ac1 = [a1**5 for a1 in xrange(10000000)]
    time.sleep(5)
    ac2 = [a1**5 for a1 in xrange(10000000)]
    time.sleep(5)
    ac3 = [a1**5 for a1 in xrange(10000000)]
```

Comment: It is my understanding that python never really specifies *when* or even *if* memory gets returned to the OS -- Only when python objects are "freed" (meaning that the memory they occupied is available to be re-used by new objects).

Comment: What happens if you move `gc.collect()` outside of the `process_alternative` function and into your `while True`, so you aren't still keeping references to your giant data structure when you run the collector?

Comment: Seems that it does not matter where gc.collect() is called. I put it before time.sleep, and resources are still hold by process. Top is showing me that process is not consuming cpu (0%) but still holding memory (21%, and around 800Mb in RES)

Comment: The Python garbage collector only deals with *circular references*; two or more objects that only refer to one another. Most objects are removed when their reference count drops to 0, but a circular reference keeps the ref count alive unless the GC breaks the circle.

Comment: But mgilson is correct; your OS will not re-use memory Python has freed until it is actually needed elsewhere. This is a good strategy; processes usually shrink and expand dynamically over their lifetime, and keeping memory allocated for longer is a performance benefit.

Comment: Will Python handle a class differently from a function? My understanding is that they're all just "objects" (loose terms) but i've witnessed classes being treated completely different in terms of freeing up memory and handling system calls outside of Python.
Try putting the function into a class and let it run through and "die" accordingly, then use `collect()` in the while loop if not automatically released. Aware of the fact that the OS will not claim the memory space unless needed and freed, but again, seen some strange behaviors with classes the last few days (don't know why specifically)

Comment: It's really weird: if my function just allocates memory as arrays, when it finishes, memory is freed correctly. Check my Edit2 as a test example

Comment: @Torxed: Function locals are just references that are cleaned up when the function completes. That is still a reference count falling back to 0 and is *not* handled by the garbage collector.

Comment: Have you checked object counts? `len(gc.get_objects())` at different points in your code. GC tracks any object that could potentially form a circular reference, so classes and containers. If that count continues to grow and never drop there may be a problem somewhere holding on to objects too long.

Comment: O_O really confused now... after typing this last line len(gc.get_objects()), memory is freed correctly... Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I do not know why, but process still hold memory, even when I set an explicit call to gc.collect().

After some playing, and thanks to Martijn Pieters, a solution appeared. Calling

```
len(gc.get_objects())
```

frees all accessed memory, and keeps process on right resources when it's not busy. Strange, but true.

Comment: This is not working for me. Can you please check again?