# why can not free memory in python, even using del and gc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, h5py

A lot of HDF5 files need to be processed. This is related to calculate `ndarray`. Every HDF5 file is about 800M. I used loop and function to do this. However, the memory was consumed rapidly.

I used `del` and `gc.collect()` to free memory, but  it can not help. And, a large of ‘modified memory’ was produced（I find out it in resource monitor of windows OS）.

The software: python3.7, jupyter notebook, windows 7 OS.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os,glob,h5py,gc
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
def DLmodel(dataset,bands2,ratio):
    #a trained deep learning model was applicated 
    morm_para = pd.read_hdf(r'I:\HY_project\calibration\blackbodyDN\HY1C_oneline\H1C_OCT_0720_FrameNumber0_train_stats_'+bands2+'.h5',key=bands2)    
    norm_dataset = (dataset - morm_para['mean']) / morm_para['std']
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'I:\HY_project\calibration\blackbodyDN\blackbody_model_'+ bands2+ '.h5')
    simulated_value = model.predict(norm_dataset)
    mat = np.full((simulated_value.shape[0],2),0.0)
    simulated_value.shape = (simulated_value.shape[0])
    mat[:,0] = simulated_value
    mat[:,1] = simulated_value/ratio
    return mat,mat.shape[0],mat.shape[1]


def simulation(file,ratio):
    # processing HDF5 file

    # 4 parameters
    bands = ['DN_412','DN_443','DN_490','DN_520','DN_565','DN_670','DN_750','DN_865']
    bands2 = ['Band412','Band443','Band490','Band520','Band565','Band670','Band750','Band865']
    gain = np.array([0.0129, 0.0118, 0.0107, 0.0115, 0.0101, 0.0077, 0.0047, 0.0026])
    offset = [0.013705,0.013545, 0.012612, 0.01255, 0.01204,0.0108225, 0.01032,0.00589]

    #open file and group
    h5 = h5py.File(file,'a')
    try:
        extra = h5.create_group('Extra Data')
    except:
        extra = h5['Extra Data'] 
    try:    
        smr = h5.create_group('scanline mean radiance')
    except:
        smr = h5['scanline mean radiance']

    #processing for every dataset node 
    for j, band in enumerate(bands):  
        #read dataset
        radiance = (np.mean(h5['Geophysical Data/'+band][:,:],axis = 1) * gain[j] + offset[j])* 1.0
        radiance.shape = (radiance.shape[0],1)
        try:
            smr.create_dataset('scanline mean radiance_'+band[3:],(radiance.shape[0], radiance.shape[1]), dtype='f',data = radiance)
        except:
            pass
        sza = h5['Scan Line Attributes/Center Solar Zenith Angle'][:,:]   
        dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((sza,radiance),axis=1), columns = ['sza', 'radiance'])
        dataset['sza'] = np.cos(dataset['sza']*np.pi/180.0) 

        #a trained deep learning model was applicated 
        mat,row, column = DLmodel(dataset,bands2[j],ratio[j])

        try:
            extra.create_dataset('Ext_'+band[3:],(row, column), dtype='f',data = mat)
        except:
            continue
    h5.close()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    files = glob.glob(r'H:\HY1BL1A\DNsubBlack\H1B_OPER_OCT_L1A*.h5')
    pbar=tqdm(total=len(files),desc='process:')
    ratio = np.array([3.88372, 4.05084, 4.61682243, 3.9826 , 4.31683, 5.09090, 5.08510, 7.34615])  

    for i, file in enumerate(files):
        simulation(file,ratio)
        gc.collect()
        pbar.update(1)
    pbar.close()
```

I want to free enough memory after every loop.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489585/python-is-not-freeing-memory

Comment: It sounds like this is just all the file data that you modified backing up in memory because it cannot be written to storage as quickly as your program is writing. What makes you think this has anything to do with anything Python is doing with its memory management?